# Car Animation Reset At a Specific Range

Tags: javascript, animation

What the aim for this code is, is to make a car and a cloud move from opposite sides of the page over to each image's respected adjacent side. I've gotten them to move. But they continue to move past the browsers viewing space. What I would like to know is an effective way to reset the code to make the car and cloud return to their original positions, and move once again. Basically, I want to loop the car and cloud through their code. I have looked around, and I remember learning something in my first semester JavaScript course back 2 years ago that would help me do exactly that, just I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Here's what I got up to this point.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Car Animation</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #AADDCC;
        }
        #imgMyCar{
        position:absolute;
        right:-600px;
        bottom:0px;

        }
        #imgMyCloud{
        position: absolute;
        left: -615px;
        top: 0px;

        }

    </style>
    <script>
    var carObject, cloudObject, counter;
    function setUp(){
    carObject=document.getElementById("imgMyCar");// set the carObject to the image tag
    cloudObject=document.getElementById("imgMyCloud");
    counter=-400;//initiliaze the counter to -600 so that the car is slightly off the right side of the screen.
    moveIt(); // call the moveIt function 

    }
    function moveIt(){
    counter=counter + 5;
    carObject.style.right=counter + "px";
    cloudObject.style.left=counter + "px";
    setTimeout(moveIt,10);

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setUp()">

    <img alt="car" id="imgMyCar" src="car1.png" />
    <img alt="cloud" id="imgMyCloud" src="clouds.png" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to test whether the position of the images is beyond the the browser viewport, and if so reset their positions.

Comment: Could you provide us with a jsfiddle so we can better see what exactly the issue is? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks thatidiotguy. You're answer helped a lot!

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question and then accept it (by clicking the check mark) instead of editing your question. (Since you are a new user, there may be a waiting period before you are allowed to do this.)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. And yeah it say's I need to wait 8 hours I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can make functional switch `direction` value. Please check the change. I hope you get answer what you want.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Car Animation</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #AADDCC;
        }
        #imgMyCar{
        position:absolute;
        right:-600px;
        bottom:0px;

        }
        #imgMyCloud{
        position: absolute;
        left: -615px;
        top: 0px;

        }

    </style>
    <script>
    var carObject, cloudObject, counter, direction;
    function setUp(){
    carObject=document.getElementById("imgMyCar");// set the carObject to the image tag
    cloudObject=document.getElementById("imgMyCloud");
    counter=-400;//initiliaze the counter to -600 so that the car is slightly off the right side of the screen.
    direction = 1; // set the direction
    moveIt(); // call the moveIt function 

    }
    function moveIt(){
        counter=counter + (direction * 5);
        carObject.style.right=counter + "px";
        cloudObject.style.left=counter + "px";
        if(counter > 500) {
            direction = -1;
        } else if(counter < -400) {
            direction = 1;
        }
        setTimeout(moveIt,10);

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setUp()">
    javascript animation

    <img alt="car" id="imgMyCar" src="car1.png" />
    <img alt="cloud" id="imgMyCloud" src="clouds.png" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Edward. That's pretty cool actually, I didn't think to reverse the animation's directions. Not really the answer I was looking for, but still works!
I did manage to get what I wanted though. 
Much appreciated!